# When using android:autoLink, non-linked text changes color on click

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, autolink

I have a TextView that I have set `android:autoLink="web"` on, and it works just fine, but the non-linked text changes from whitish to black when I click on it, for example if I have the text `Check out Google's site: www.google.com`, the `Check out Google` part **changes color**.

I have this `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` that I set as the view of an `AlertDialog`, perhaps that has something to do with it since this **does not happen** when I use `android:autoLink="web"` outside of an `AlertDialog`... Anyone know what might be happening here??

Comment: i am looking for the same answer, any clue?